# Xcode7 and array.filter method misunderstanding

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, swift2

Hello  there i am using the latest Xcode 7 beta 6 and appears to be a problem with the filter method of an array.

in the following example i am trying to reproduce this :
search the array and if you find any numbers biggest than 40 throw them away and after you do all that return the array filtered. It used to work with Xcode 6.4 but now it doesn't what am i missing here? cause in the argument once i type filter and press enter i get this :

```
(includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool
```

this is the code for Xcode 6.4

```
var someIntArray2 = [1,34,56,92,12,32,124,23,1293]

someIntArray2.filter({$0 < $40})
```

Comment: Take the `$` before the `40` out. (`someIntArray2.filter{$0 < 40}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my previous comment:

In `someIntArray2.filter({$0 < $40})`, the `$40` is checking for the 40th argument passed to the closure and compares the 0th parameter to it, but the closure that the `filter` method expects only takes one argument.

The line should instead be converted to `someIntArray2.filter({$0 < 40})` which will compare the passed argument to the *number 40* as intended.

---

(Since the closure is the last argument of the function, it is also possible to remove the parentheses which would turn the line into `someIntArray2.filter{$0 < 40}`)

Comment: yeah really thank you. i am a new beginner with swift myself and you just helped me completely understand closure mechanism. perhaps now you can explain me the different a trailing closure has except from the aesthetic?